# Error when getting "href" value from link on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I ran into an error on IE with giving url as an example: http://example.com.br_ç

When I put this url in the href property and try to access it using javascript, IE throws an "Not specified error".

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
console.log(link.href);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com.br_ç" id="link">test</a>
```

Firefox writes the correct url and Chrome writes the url enconded.
I searched about it and I reached the IDN (International Domain Name), but nothing that leads to the error or if it's an IE bug.

Does anyone have an idea?